# Pandas set values from another DataFrame based on dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This:

```
periods = 5 * 3                                                               
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(dict(                                                  
  v1=numpy.arange(2, 2 + periods) * 2,                                        
  v2=numpy.arange(3, 3 +periods) * 3),                                        
  index=pandas.date_range('2023-01-01', periods=periods, freq='8H'))          
print(df1)                                                                    
                                                                              
periods = 3                                                                   
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(dict(                                                  
  v3=numpy.arange(4, 4 + periods) * 4,                                        
  v4=numpy.arange(5, 5 + periods) * 5),                                       
  index=pandas.date_range('2023-01-02', periods=periods, freq='2D'))          
print(df2)                                                                    
                                                                              
df1.loc[df1.index.date, ['v3', 'v4']] = df2                                   
print(df1)
```

results in:

```
                     v1  v2
2023-01-01 00:00:00   4   9
2023-01-01 08:00:00   6  12
2023-01-01 16:00:00   8  15
2023-01-02 00:00:00  10  18
2023-01-02 08:00:00  12  21
2023-01-02 16:00:00  14  24
2023-01-03 00:00:00  16  27
2023-01-03 08:00:00  18  30
2023-01-03 16:00:00  20  33
2023-01-04 00:00:00  22  36
2023-01-04 08:00:00  24  39
2023-01-04 16:00:00  26  42
2023-01-05 00:00:00  28  45
2023-01-05 08:00:00  30  48
2023-01-05 16:00:00  32  51
            v3  v4
2023-01-02  16  25
2023-01-04  20  30
2023-01-06  24  35
                     v1  v2    v3    v4
2023-01-01 00:00:00   4   9   NaN   NaN
2023-01-01 08:00:00   6  12   NaN   NaN
2023-01-01 16:00:00   8  15   NaN   NaN
2023-01-02 00:00:00  10  18  16.0  25.0
2023-01-02 08:00:00  12  21  16.0  25.0
2023-01-02 16:00:00  14  24  16.0  25.0
2023-01-03 00:00:00  16  27   NaN   NaN
2023-01-03 08:00:00  18  30   NaN   NaN
2023-01-03 16:00:00  20  33   NaN   NaN
2023-01-04 00:00:00  22  36  20.0  30.0
2023-01-04 08:00:00  24  39  20.0  30.0
2023-01-04 16:00:00  26  42  20.0  30.0
2023-01-05 00:00:00  28  45   NaN   NaN
2023-01-05 08:00:00  30  48   NaN   NaN
2023-01-05 16:00:00  32  51   NaN   NaN
```

where each value from `df2` is copied to `df1` whenever date of `df1` matches the date of `df2` (i.e. ignoring the time component).

However, changing the `df1` index to have a time component (`01:00` in this example), i.e.:

```
periods = 5 * 3                                                             
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(dict(                                                
  v1=numpy.arange(2, 2 + periods) * 2,                                      
  v2=numpy.arange(3, 3 +periods) * 3),                                      
  index=pandas.date_range('2023-01-01 01:00', periods=periods, freq='8H'))  
print(df1)                                                                  
                                                                            
periods = 3                                                                 
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(dict(                                                
  v3=numpy.arange(4, 4 + periods) * 4,                                      
  v4=numpy.arange(5, 5 + periods) * 5),                                     
  index=pandas.date_range('2023-01-02', periods=periods, freq='2D'))        
print(df2)                                                                  
                                                                            
df1.loc[df1.index.date, ['v3', 'v4']] = df2                                 
print(df1)
```

results in:

```
                     v1  v2
2023-01-01 01:00:00   4   9
2023-01-01 09:00:00   6  12
2023-01-01 17:00:00   8  15
2023-01-02 01:00:00  10  18
2023-01-02 09:00:00  12  21
2023-01-02 17:00:00  14  24
2023-01-03 01:00:00  16  27
2023-01-03 09:00:00  18  30
2023-01-03 17:00:00  20  33
2023-01-04 01:00:00  22  36
2023-01-04 09:00:00  24  39
2023-01-04 17:00:00  26  42
2023-01-05 01:00:00  28  45
2023-01-05 09:00:00  30  48
2023-01-05 17:00:00  32  51
            v3  v4
2023-01-02  16  25
2023-01-04  20  30
2023-01-06  24  35
...
KeyError: "None of [Index([2023-01-01, 2023-01-01, 2023-01-01, 2023-01-02, 2023-01-02, 2023-01-02,\n       2023-01-03, 2023-01-03, 2023-01-03, 2023-01-04, 2023-01-04, 2023-01-04,\n       2023-01-05, 2023-01-05, 2023-01-05],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

so apparently:

```
df1.loc[df1.index.date, ['v3', 'v4']] = df2
```

is not the appropriate way to set values based on date (i.e. ignoring time).

Questions:

- Why doesn't it work when there's a time component?
- Since it doesn't work with a time component, why does it work when there's no time component by matching *all* times (i.e. not only `00:00`)?
- What would be the correct way to do what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first example, you are lucky to have some datetime with `00:00:00`, so you can use `.loc`. In your second example, you have not this kind of datetime so you can't select any rows.

The right way is probably to use `merge` after `normalize` index:

```
out = df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1.index.normalize(), right_index=True, how='left')
print(out)

# Output
                     v1  v2    v3    v4
2023-01-01 01:00:00   4   9   NaN   NaN
2023-01-01 09:00:00   6  12   NaN   NaN
2023-01-01 17:00:00   8  15   NaN   NaN
2023-01-02 01:00:00  10  18  16.0  25.0
2023-01-02 09:00:00  12  21  16.0  25.0
2023-01-02 17:00:00  14  24  16.0  25.0
2023-01-03 01:00:00  16  27   NaN   NaN
2023-01-03 09:00:00  18  30   NaN   NaN
2023-01-03 17:00:00  20  33   NaN   NaN
2023-01-04 01:00:00  22  36  20.0  30.0
2023-01-04 09:00:00  24  39  20.0  30.0
2023-01-04 17:00:00  26  42  20.0  30.0
2023-01-05 01:00:00  28  45   NaN   NaN
2023-01-05 09:00:00  30  48   NaN   NaN
2023-01-05 17:00:00  32  51   NaN   NaN
```

**Update**

> Why are rows with non-00:00 time selected though?

They are not, you reindex your dataframe and duplicate rows with `00:00` time:

```
>>> df1.loc[df1.index.date]
            v1  v2
2023-01-01   4   9
2023-01-01   4   9
2023-01-01   4   9
2023-01-02  10  18  # <- original 2023-01-02 00:00:00 (10, 18)
2023-01-02  10  18  # <- dupe, not 2023-01-02 08:00:00 (12, 21)
2023-01-02  10  18  # <- dupe, not 2023-01-02 16:00:00 (14, 24)
2023-01-03  16  27
2023-01-03  16  27
2023-01-03  16  27
2023-01-04  22  36
2023-01-04  22  36
2023-01-04  22  36
2023-01-05  28  45
2023-01-05  28  45
2023-01-05  28  45
```

Comment: Thanks! In the first example, why are rows with non-`00:00` time selected though?

Comment: They are not :-). In fact, you duplicates each `00:00` row 3 times

Comment: Why does `df1.loc[df1.index.date]` reindex in 1st example, but not in the 2nd though? I.e. why does it reindex from `2023-01-02 08:00` to `2023-01-02` in the first example, but not from `2023-01-02 01:00` to `2023-01-02` in the second example?

Comment: `2023-01-01 00:00:00 == 2023-01-01` and `2023-01-02 01:00 != 2023-01-02`. In the second example you don't have any date ended by midnight so the indexing failed.

Comment: If `2023-01-01` matches *only* `2023-01-01 00:00`, why did it match / update the *other two* rows (`08:00` and `16:00`) as well then? I.e. there's an inconsistency - in 1st example it matches both `00:00` and non-`00:00` rows, but in 2nd example it doesn't match either of the two. Why would having (1st example) or not having (2nd example) a `00:00` row change how *the other rows* (`08:00` and `09:00` in this case) are treated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252198/discussion-between-corralien-and-levant-pied).