# Pandas concatenate strings and numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this:

```
n = 5                                            
df = pandas.DataFrame(dict(j=numpy.repeat(0, n)))
df['j'] = 'prefix-'                              
df['j'] += numpy.arange(n).astype('U')           
df['j'] += '-suffix'                             
print(df)
```

which produces:

```
                 j
0  prefix-0-suffix
1  prefix-1-suffix
2  prefix-2-suffix
3  prefix-3-suffix
4  prefix-4-suffix
```

Is there a way to do this (reasonably) in one line?

I tried:

```
df['j'] = 'prefix-' + numpy.arange(n).astype('U') + '-suffix'
```

but that resulted in this error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U7'), dtype('<U21')) -> None
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert as string using [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and [`pd.RangeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html)

```
# df['j'] = 'prefix-' + df['j'].astype(str) + '-suffix'
df['j'] = 'prefix-' + pd.RangeIndex(n).astype(str) + '-suffix'
print(df)

# Output
                 j
0  prefix-0-suffix
1  prefix-1-suffix
2  prefix-2-suffix
3  prefix-3-suffix
4  prefix-4-suffix
```

Comment: Nice, pandas-only solution, I like it - thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you to solve your problem :-)

Comment: I remember this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75587171/15239951). Do you understand the date problem? :)

Comment: `I remember this question.` Hahah you have good memory :) `Do you understand the date problem?` No, I think I gave up on that with a workaround :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a reason you want to use `numpy.arange(n).astype('U')`, you can wrap this call in a Series:

```python
df['j'] = 'prefix-' + pandas.Series(numpy.arange(n).astype('U'), index=df.index) + '-suffix'
```

If the goal is simply to get the final result, you can reduce your code after `n = 5` to a one-line initialization of df:

```python
df = pandas.DataFrame({'j': 'prefix-' + pandas.Series(range(n)).astype(str) + '-suffix'})
```

Comment: `Assuming there is a reason you want to use numpy.arange(n).astype('U')` No, not really, just what I thought of to try - thanks!